# flutter async function not executing

Tags: flutter, asynchronous

When I am passing arguments into a function like this:

```
 Future<APITestObj>_testFunction(string acctNum, id) async {
         APITestObj testObjec = await ApiHelper.wrapper(context () => this.api.APITestObj(acctNum, id);

return testObject;

}
```

and then call the function from inside of a button function like this:

```
onTap() {
 _testFunction(13, 9);

}
```

the function is not being executed. Can someone please explain why?

example error message: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDXDj.png)

Comment: it's still didn't work my request is still null

Comment: actually it looks like I get response of no such method error

Answer (score 0):

`_testFunction` returns a Future, so you should change

```
onTap() {
 _testFunction(13, 9);

}
```

to this:

```
onTap() async {
var result = await _testFunction(13, 9);
print('$result')
}
```

Comment: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'codeUnits' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: codeUnits

Comment: @ElderiedMckinney can you attach the whole error message?

Comment: there is a link that say example error message at the top if you tap it. There will be a screenshot of the error